# How can I calculate all distances family and extract all results in K-means

Tags: python, distance, euclidean-distance

I'd like to use K-means distance calculator instead of Euclidean distance, and compare the results between them.
In other words, use the family of distance measurement in clusters instead of Euclidean distances to compare the results on more than one dataset.
In addition to using the tools available for this technique to evaluate these metrics.
If you are interested, I will give you more information.
I have a dataset that I would like to use. I have attached a sample of the dataset, which is Iris dataset. You can use it to implement the metrics and extract them, in addition to the required evaluation.

Table The Reviewed Distance Measures That works with K-means
Distance metric family  Distance

1- L1 Distance metric family:
Canberra Distance (CanD),
Sørensen Distance (SD),
Non-Intersection Distance (NID)

2- Lp Minkowski distance measures family:
Manhattan Distance (MD),
Chebyshev Distance (CD),
Euclidean Distance (ED)

3- Squared Chord distance family:
Bhattachayya Distance (BD),
Hellinger Distance (HeD)

4- Squared L2 distance family:
Squared Euclidean Distance (SED),
Clark Distance (ClD),
Neyman χ2 Distance (NCSD),
Pearson χ2 Distance (PCSD),
Squared χ2 Distance (SCSD),
Probabilistic Symmetric χ2 Distance (PSCSD),
Divergence Distance (DivD),
Additive Symmetric χ2 Distance (ASCSD),
Average Distance (AD),
Mean Censored Euclidean Distance (MCED),
Squared Chi-Squared Distance (SCSD)

5- Shannon entropy family:
Jeffreys Distance (JefD)

6- Other distance family:
Avg Distance (AvgD),
Kumar- Johnson Distance (KJD),
Taneja Distance (TanD),
Pearson Distance (PeaD),
Correlation Distance (CorD),
Squared Pearson Distance (SPeaD),
Hamming Distance (HamD),
Hausdorff Distance (HauD)

Note:
Performance Evaluation
Different measures are available for evaluating the performance of clustering techniques. In this study, five measures will be used, accuracy, precision, F1, recall and the Adjusted rand index (ARI).

Dataset:  [UCI Machine Learning Repository: Iris Data Set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris)

Comment: So, to make sure; you need to perform K-mean clustering using another metric than the L2-norm?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.